# Сделать кнопку доступной, если заполнены все поля (Android)

Tags: android, java

Есть 4 EditText, как только все заполнены, нужно сделать кнопку доступной

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно на каждый EditText повешать TextWatcher

```
et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    //Проверить пусты ли EditTextы, если заполнены, активировать кнопку

}});
```

Comment: спасибо, то что надо